# How to import orthomosiac from metashape into QGIS and preserve ortho appearance?

Tags: qgis, orthophoto

[image: Bea][image]

The beautiful image that you see is an orthomosaic [apparently this is not a yet a tag on this forum] generated in Agisoft Metashape [also not a yet a tag] with imagery captured with drone mounted with a MicaSense multispectral camera.

The color television static image is what I see when I import the orthomosaic into QGIS. If I fudge with the brightness and contrast I can get a better looking image but not the pristine vibrant image you see below. When I examine the properties of the image it gives me 6 bands and 3 of which are assigned R, G, and B. I feel that this assignment is the issue but honestly am not sure.

The MicaSense camera is used for RedEdge imagery and should have 5 bands from my understanding. I am having a hard time deciphering what Band1-6 actually represent and need to know for my analysis. What can I do to understand the wavelengths each band correspond to and to generate a usable image for analysis in QGIS?

`gdalinfo` (GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20) returns this:

```
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Orthomosaic.tif
Size is 15407, 7125
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-77.015632553681499,42.879833861776198)
Pixel Size = (0.000000308213000,-0.000000226674000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -77.0156326,  42.8798339) ( 77d 0'56.28"W, 42d52'47.40"N)
Lower Left  ( -77.0156326,  42.8782188) ( 77d 0'56.28"W, 42d52'41.59"N)
Upper Right ( -77.0108839,  42.8798339) ( 77d 0'39.18"W, 42d52'47.40"N)
Lower Right ( -77.0108839,  42.8782188) ( 77d 0'39.18"W, 42d52'41.59"N)
Center      ( -77.0132582,  42.8790263) ( 77d 0'47.73"W, 42d52'44.49"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 7704x3563, 3852x1782, 1926x891, 963x446, 482x223, 241x112
  Unit Type: metre
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 7704x3563, 3852x1782, 1926x891, 963x446, 482x223, 241x112
  Unit Type: metre
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Overviews: 7704x3563, 3852x1782, 1926x891, 963x446, 482x223, 241x112
  Unit Type: metre
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Overviews: 7704x3563, 3852x1782, 1926x891, 963x446, 482x223, 241x112
  Unit Type: metre
Band 5 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Overviews: 7704x3563, 3852x1782, 1926x891, 963x446, 482x223, 241x112
  Unit Type: metre
Band 6 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Overviews: 7704x3563, 3852x1782, 1926x891, 963x446, 482x223, 241x112
  Unit Type: metre
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
```

These errors also occur with `tiffinfo`. Trying to read with Python's PIL, which I think is an independent code not using `libtiff` fails to open it:

```
>>> im = Image.open("./test.tif") # reads a test tiff okay...
>>> im = Image.open("./Orthomosaic.tif")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2590, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file './Orthomosaic.tif'
```

Comment: Does the documentation for the hardware not say what the bands are? Can you point us to a sample file we can experiment with?

Comment: @Spacedman The Micasense user manual specifies bands 1-5 as blue, green, red, Near IR and Red Edge. Nothing is listed for band 6. I uploaded a file for experimentation onto google drive can be accesed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HvMRd-A5Tw7eQBSxO2D2jIA2f_WXnjsp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: gdal is giving me some warnings on that file: "Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples." which might be a symptom. Something's not right with it...

Comment: It loads as an image into Metashape and shows as grayscale, but it looks smooth and correct. Must be using a different TIFF reader to GDAL (and therefore QGIS). ImageMagick `convert` gives same error as GDAL. Not sure what else I can try...

Comment: Read into R using the `raster` package, the metadata says the values range from basically 0 to 65535, but when the raster is read it gets values from -32767 to +32767. When plotted there's a clear discontinuity at 0. But even fixing that (by plotting `abs(rgbstack)` ) there's a mystery in that the image should be quite green but its not obvious that one band is much larger than the others and therefore the green band.

Comment: Run gdalinfo and add the report into your question.

Comment: gdalinfo shows nothing out of the ordinary except the warnings I put in a comment above. Python's PIL refuses to read it with `"IOError: cannot identify image file './Orthomosaic.tif'"`. I can edit the Q...

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting without alpha channel from metashape.  When we had similar problems this seemed to solve it. In the export dialog you can uncheck a checkbox.

The observed difference from gdalinfo shows a different image size (+1 pixel without alpha channel) and for the alpha image gdalinfo states:

> Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Alpha

whereas the alpha channel likely is the last channel.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer to include a screenshot showing the export dialog and the checkbox that needs to be unchecked?